# MySQL Query Timeout in PHP script, Upgrading to VPS

Tags: mysql, php, timeout

We've recently had to upgrade to a VPS from shared hosting because we were getting timeouts on a vital SQL query running from a PHP script.

This PHP script runs hundreds of times a day at random occasions, many times concurrently.

The error I found out while manually testing the PHP script was with this line:

```
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) { . . .
```

It would occasionally get the `(2013) “Lost connection to MySQL server during query”.` error.

Here is the query in question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Inventory.id,
  Inventory.SKU AS inventory_sku,
  Inventory.Quantity AS inventory_quantity,
  MasterSKU.SKU_1,
  MasterSKU.SKU_2,
  MasterSKU.SKU_3,
  MasterSKU.SKU_4,
  MasterSKU.SKU_5,
  MasterSKU.SKU_6,
  MasterSKU.SKU_7,
  MasterSKU.SKU_8,
  MasterSKU.SKU_9,
  MasterSKU.SKU_10,
  MasterSKU.SKU_11,
  MasterSKU.SKU_12,
  MasterSKU.SKU_13,
  MasterSKU.SKU_14,
  MasterSKU.SKU_15,
  MasterSKU.SKU_16,
  MasterSKU.SKU_17,
  MasterSKU.SKU_18,
  MasterSKU.SKU_19,
  MasterSKU.SKU_20,
  MasterSKU.MultSKU,
  MasterSKU.QtySKU,
  MasterSKU.AltSKU,
  MasterSKU.SKU,
      '$qty' AS sold_quantity,
      '$sku' AS sold_sku
FROM eBayOrders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MasterSKU
    ON MasterSKU.SKU = '$sku'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Inventory
    ON Inventory.SKU IN (MasterSKU.AltSKU, MasterSKU.SKU_1, MasterSKU.SKU_2, MasterSKU.SKU_3, MasterSKU.SKU_4, MasterSKU.SKU_5, MasterSKU.SKU_6, MasterSKU.SKU_7, MasterSKU.SKU_8, MasterSKU.SKU_9, MasterSKU.SKU_10, MasterSKU.SKU_11, MasterSKU.SKU_12, MasterSKU.SKU_13, MasterSKU.SKU_14, MasterSKU.SKU_15, MasterSKU.SKU_16, MasterSKU.SKU_17, MasterSKU.SKU_18, MasterSKU.SKU_19, MasterSKU.SKU_20);
```

On localhost testing, a single instance of this query was running anywhere from 5 - 6.5 seconds.

I was able to optimize this a little bit and get it around to 4 seconds by taking away `DISTINCT` and adding `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
  Inventory.id,
  Inventory.SKU AS inventory_sku,
  Inventory.Quantity AS inventory_quantity,
  MasterSKU.SKU_1,
  MasterSKU.SKU_2,
  MasterSKU.SKU_3,
  MasterSKU.SKU_4,
  MasterSKU.SKU_5,
  MasterSKU.SKU_6,
  MasterSKU.SKU_7,
  MasterSKU.SKU_8,
  MasterSKU.SKU_9,
  MasterSKU.SKU_10,
  MasterSKU.SKU_11,
  MasterSKU.SKU_12,
  MasterSKU.SKU_13,
  MasterSKU.SKU_14,
  MasterSKU.SKU_15,
  MasterSKU.SKU_16,
  MasterSKU.SKU_17,
  MasterSKU.SKU_18,
  MasterSKU.SKU_19,
  MasterSKU.SKU_20,
  MasterSKU.MultSKU,
  MasterSKU.QtySKU,
  MasterSKU.AltSKU,
  MasterSKU.SKU,
      '$quantitypurchased' AS sold_quantity,
      '$sku' AS sold_sku
FROM eBayOrders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MasterSKU
    ON MasterSKU.SKU = '$sku'
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Inventory
    ON Inventory.SKU IN (MasterSKU.AltSKU, MasterSKU.SKU_1, MasterSKU.SKU_2, MasterSKU.SKU_3, MasterSKU.SKU_4, MasterSKU.SKU_5, MasterSKU.SKU_6, MasterSKU.SKU_7, MasterSKU.SKU_8, MasterSKU.SKU_9, MasterSKU.SKU_10, MasterSKU.SKU_11, MasterSKU.SKU_12, MasterSKU.SKU_13, MasterSKU.SKU_14, MasterSKU.SKU_15, MasterSKU.SKU_16, MasterSKU.SKU_17, MasterSKU.SKU_18, MasterSKU.SKU_19, MasterSKU.SKU_20)
GROUP BY Inventory.id;
```

With this I was able to get it down to around 4 seconds (again, for a single instance... while running concurrently on our shared hosting it was giving a timing out error after 30 seconds)

Now, with Shared Hosting, we were not able to change our MySQL configurations such as `wait_timeout` `net_read_timeout` and `net_write_timeout`.

My idea is to change these configurations to a near maximum number, and also enable the [MySQL Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) to get log files.

Additionally, a thought came into my head to a `processed` tinyint column to my table and check for a successful `UPDATE` which is at the `while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`, and if it gets this far, look for a successful query and add another query to `UPDATE processed = 1`.  This way I can make sure the entire script has run till its end, and reference this in my database.

I've been working on this project for several months, and these timeout issues are killing the system so need to be fixed.

We are in process of doing the migration to VPS right now, I am wondering if anyone can think of a further way to optimize the query or tables, or any mysql configuration settings we can set to ensure my script and queries run 100% of the time.

Tables in question:

: `MasterSKU`

```
CREATE TABLE `MasterSKU` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SKU` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `AltSKU` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `QtySKU` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `MultSKU` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `SKU_1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_6` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_7` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_8` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_9` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_10` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_11` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_12` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_13` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_14` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_15` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_16` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_17` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_18` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_19` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU_20` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `processed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `comments` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `SKU` (`SKU`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7815 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

: `Inventory`

```
CREATE TABLE `Inventory` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `SKU` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `Quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `soldout` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `reorderamt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `zeroday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `category` text,
 `supplier` text,
 `channel` text,
 `location` text,
 `incoming` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastmodified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `createdtime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `SKU` (`SKU`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4753 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

: `eBayOrders`

```
CREATE TABLE `eBayOrders` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `OrderLineItemID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `SalesRecordNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `BuyerUserID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `BuyerEmail` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `SKU` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `TransactionPrice` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `createdtime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `ExtendedOrderID` (`OrderLineItemID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11668 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not splay an array across columns.  Instead have another table to `JOIN` to, with up to 24 *rows* of SKUs.

In doing so, this un-optimizable clause goes away:

```
Inventory.SKU IN ( ... 24 columns of `MasterSKU` ... )
```

In its place will be a simple `JOIN` that *can* be optimized.

If you need more help, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables in question.

**More**

Start with a table something like:

```
CREATE TABLE OtherSkus (
    MasterSku VARCHAR(20) CHARSET=latin1 NOT NULL, -- for JOINing
    AltSku VARCHAR(20) CHARSET=latin1 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MasterSku, AltSku)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then see how you can shrink the 24 SKU columns down to perhaps only 1.

Comment: Really appreciate the advice.  This was/is an ambitious first real SQL project, so I am sure things are not entirely optimized properly. I added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` results in the original question.  The logic behind the `MasterSKU` table is a `QtySKU` which reflects the Quantity to be deducted for the SKU.  `MultSKU` is a tinyint `0` or `1`.  If `1`, the PHP script knows the SKU has Multiple SKU's associated with it, up to 20 `SKU_1 - SKU_20`.  If `0` then there is just one SKU associated with it, and it looks only to `AltSKU`.

Comment: The `SKU` column has no reference to the *actual* SKU, just taken from the eBay API Listings SKU. `SKU` is just a reference SKU to get the actual SKU/SKUs associated with the eBay listing (as I said previously, either in `AltSKU` or `SKU_1` all the way up to a possible `SKU_20`

Comment: "Up to" -- all the more reason to put them in another table, not in columns.

Comment: Surely `SKU` is always shorter than 255?  Recommend you find some civilized limit.

Comment: Please use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  The latter is going away.

Comment: Are you suggesting I put SKU_1 through SKU_20 into 20 separate tables? I always figured it would be a faster query the less joins.. this would suggest up to 20 possible joins or more in a new query that will give me the same result. Maybe I am not understanding this correctly I'm going to try and wrap my head around it more tomorrow when I'm working on it.

Comment: And thank you, I will make them all innodb.  varchars can also be optimized too yes

Comment: 20 _rows_ in _one_ column of _one_ table.  See `GROUP_CONCAT()` as one way of collecting all of them.

Comment: Very interesting! Had never considered that before. Will have to do some testing with this.  Could be what I was looking for.